# Loop through MongoDB docs?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb, express

With a basic AJAX web app running locally, a Form POSTs data through Express/Node.js to MongoDB, and a button onClick responds in a rendering of the Mongo document(s) in a div-box.

**Using *[Swig](http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/)* for templating, onClick of the button is only returning a right-brace to appear in the html div-box.**

> }

**How can this be edited to loop through each MongoDB document?**

wrapper.html:

```
{% for go in allDOCs %}
_wrapperGet('{"getting":"{{ keyName }}"}')
{% endfor %}
```

..where the ajax posts the wrapper data in index.html:

```
<!-- For the Returned Fields -->
<div id="theResponse">

</div><!-- /.theResponse -->
```

console.log(returnValue); is listing the mongoDB documents:

```
{"keyName":"Here's a Value!"}, {"keyName":"Here's another Value!"}
```

..from app.js

```
function getAllDOCs(res) {

    db.collection('dbCollectionName').find({}, {"_id":0}).toArray(function (err, docs) {

        console.log("Got the DOCs: " + docs);

        var returnValue = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < docs.length; i++)
        {
            if (returnValue == "")
            {
                returnValue = returnValue + JSON.stringify(docs[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                returnValue = returnValue + ", " + JSON.stringify(docs[i]);
            }
            console.log(docs[i]);
        }

        console.log(returnValue);

        res.render('wrapper', { allDOCs: returnValue });

    });
}
```

index.html AJAX json parsing:

```
function handleFINDbuttonResponse(data)
{
  // parse the json string
  var jsonObject = JSON.parse(data);
  $('#theResponse').append( jsonObject.getting );
}
```

Comment: This question is quite long and touches many different topics. Try to isolate your problem and ask a concise question that touches not as many topics. Then it will be easier to answer your question.

Comment: Why are you manually stringifying your docs before passing them to the template?

Comment: @user152468 cut down the code to the most relevant pieces, and reorganized the post to be more direct.. Is it better? Am really just asking how to properly format that template piece using the AJAX _wrapperGet

Comment: @JohnnyHK thanks for pointing that out.. that was from when I was including _wrapperGet in the returnValue.. Trying this without it now!

Comment: Have you tried just creating an array: `returnValue = [];` and then pushing each doc? `returnValue.push(docs[i].toJSON());`?

Comment: @JohnnyHK without stringifying the docs, console.log(returnValue) reads: [object Object], [object Object], [object Object].. And instead of a '}' appearing in the div-box, a ']' appears

Comment: @WiredPrairie trying that now! Thanks

Comment: @WiredPrairie am getting a TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'toJSON' Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using Mongoose. You should be able to just pass the docs directly without fixing it at all.

Comment: @WiredPrairie All good, thanks for the info. For whatever reason, the array [] instead of the empty string "" still generates the right-brace } and actually the returnValue has a preceding comment, curious.. Any other recommendations? Cheers, and Merry Christmas!

Comment: Passing the docs directly to the wrapper.html returns [object Object], [object Object].. for everything, hence the manual stringifying